# proving: ∀,  ∈ ℤ, $2( + )^8 ≡_4 2(^8 + ^8)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

For this question, my way of proving it is:

write: $4|(2(\binom80a^8 + \binom81a^7b + \binom82a^6b^2... \binom88b^8) - (2a^8 +2b^8)$

since $2a^8 \ and\ \ 2b^8$ are eliminated, I just need to write $4|(\binom81a^7b + \binom82a^6b^2...\binom87ab^7)$ Because I know that for all $\binom8k$ where $0<k<8,\ k\in \mathbb{Z}$, $\binom8k$ is a multiple of 8, does this suffice as proof?

My second question is, is there a simpler (shorter) way around writing out $4|\binom81a^7b + \binom82a^6b^2...\binom87ab^7$?

Comment: What could be more simple, really?

Comment: part of my question is also whether this is deemed a correct proof? I need someone with higher authority on the subject than myself to confirm this for me. I have a quiz on modular arithmetic and cardinality tomorrow.

Comment: "Correct proof" varies from prof to prof, anyway, usually on stackexchange you'll find people approving rather than dissapproving, because they get the idea. Your prof will most likely want you to follow his techniques rather than getting the idea. That's formal education.

Comment: There is a false assertion that $\binom{8}{k}$ is divisible by $8$ when $0\lt k\lt 8$. And there is  a simple approach.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I was thinking permutations rather than combinations, which is why I messed up I think.

Comment: @DharmeshSujeeun: Your proof will go through with minor modification, since all you need for mod $4$ is that $\binom{8}{k}$ is even whenever $1\lt k\lt 8$.  For modulus $8$, we would need more, since $\binom{8}{4}=70$.

Comment: Wep, j'comprends :-). À bientôt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a cases approach. If $a$ and $b$ are even, the result is clear. If $a$ and $b$ are both odd, then $(a+b)^8$ and $a^8+b^8$ are even, so the result holds.

If one of $a$ or $b$ is odd and the other even, then $(a+b)^8$ is odd, so $2(a+b)^8\equiv 2\pmod{4}$. But $a^8+b^8$ is also odd, so $2(a^8+b^8)\equiv 2\pmod{4}$.

One can strengthen the result. For example a very similar argument shows that the congruence holds modulo $8$. One can show with a bit more work that it holds modulo $32$.

Comment: Thanks a lot André, that was really helpful.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Quick question: if $a \equiv b \ (mod \ n)$ and $c \equiv b \ (mod \ n)$ then $a \equiv c \ (mod \ n)$ ?

Also, how do I make my letters within the "$$" non-italics?

Comment: Yes, if $a\equiv b\pmod{n}$ and $b\equiv c\pmod{n}$ then $a\equiv c\pmod{n}$. As to your formatting question, there is a special notation for modulus that gets everything right, a\equiv b\pmod{n}, of course between dollar signs. If you just want to get mod in non-italics within dollar signs, you can use \text{mod}. The font will be upright, but the results are less satisfactory than the first approach I mentioned.

Comment: To get the result mod $16$, use the standard and useful fact that if $x$ is odd then $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$.

Comment: Thanks again. By the way, you seem to be very knowledgeable about these things, are you a mathematician by profession by any chance?

Comment: @DharmeshSujeeun: Yes, I am a mathematician.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37749/discussion-between-dharmesh-sujeeun-and-andre-nicolas).

Comment: @DharmeshSujeeun: After a couple of negative experiences, I have avoided chat.

Comment: I understand...